# Vba Stop Data Entry sheet Entering data if checkbox is set to False

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with a data entry sheet I am designing.
I have kind of hacked together a function that copies the forms data and selected size.
I'm trying to have it do this for any size set to true, but currently if it's set to false it is still pasting in the form data on the next line.

[This is what the form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHpjT.png)

```
'''Input
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, RowInsert As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("stock")
    
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        
        RowInsert = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Find("*", .Cells(LastRow, "A"), xlValues, , , xlPrevious).row
        RowInsert = RowInsert + 1

                                         ''''This has to match the number of rows input below
        .Cells(RowInsert, "A").Resize(1, 8).Value = Array( _
            Me.txtDate.Text, _
            Me.textboxparentsku.Text, _
            Me.textboxsku.Text, _
            Me.comboboxbrand.Text, _
            Me.comboboxclosure.Text, _
            Me.comboboxgender.Text, _
            Me.comboboxmaterial.Text, _
            Me.comboboxmodel.Text _
        )
    
'Checkbox data entry

    If Me.CheckBox0k.Value = True Then ws.Range("I" & RowInsert).Value = "0k"
   With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        
        RowInsert = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Find("*", .Cells(LastRow, "A"), xlValues, , , xlPrevious).row
        RowInsert = RowInsert + 1

                                         ''''This has to match the number of rows input below
        .Cells(RowInsert, "A").Resize(1, 8).Value = Array( _
            Me.txtDate.Text, _
            Me.textboxparentsku.Text, _
            Me.textboxsku.Text, _
            Me.comboboxbrand.Text, _
            Me.comboboxclosure.Text, _
            Me.comboboxgender.Text, _
            Me.comboboxmaterial.Text, _
            Me.comboboxmodel.Text _
        )
    End With
    
    
     If Me.CheckBox05k.Value = False Then ws.Range("I" & RowInsert).Value = "" 

'Thanks Alex, If the above is false I don't want it to print anything


    If Me.CheckBox05k.Value = True Then ws.Range("I" & RowInsert).Value = "0.5k"  
    
Exit Sub
    
    
    
    End With
  
   
    
    
    Set ws = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show in the code where you want it to stop if a checkbox is set to false?

Comment: Currently it is pasting the last line  "  If Me.CheckBox05k.Value = True Then ws.Range("I" & RowInsert).Value = "0.5k"  But I want it to not paste any data in if the checkbox reports false

Comment: If you debug the code, can you check the value of Me.Checkbox05k? Because as far as I can see, it will only put "0.5k" in column I if the checkbox is true.

Comment: Or do you also not want it to print stuff in columns 1 to 8?

Comment: That's right I don't want it printing in 1-8 if it's a false result. I think I'm slowly getting it so it's pulling the data from the start of my Input section regardless. I need to somehow make that dependant on if there is a check box ticked at all, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your if-statements are only applied to the same line. You need to put everything you only want to happen if the if-statement is true inside:

```
If Me.CheckBox05k.Value = True Then
    'Everything you only want to happen now in here
End If
```

Additionally, you can also use `ElseIf` or `Else` since a checkbox can only be true or false.

So it could be something like this:

```
If Me.CheckBox0k.Value = True Then
    ws.Range("I" & RowInsert).Value = "0k"
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        RowInsert = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Find("*", .Cells(LastRow, "A"), xlValues, , , xlPrevious).Row
        RowInsert = RowInsert + 1

                                         ''''This has to match the number of rows input below
        .Cells(RowInsert, "A").Resize(1, 8).Value = Array( _
            Me.txtDate.Text, _
            Me.textboxparentsku.Text, _
            Me.textboxsku.Text, _
            Me.comboboxbrand.Text, _
            Me.comboboxclosure.Text, _
            Me.comboboxgender.Text, _
            Me.comboboxmaterial.Text, _
            Me.comboboxmodel.Text _
        )
    End With
ElseIf Me.CheckBox05k.Value = False Then
    ws.Range("I" & RowInsert).Value = ""
Else
    ws.Range("I" & RowInsert).Value = "0.5k"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you That has worked for adding each shoe line! I can't upvote yet, but you deserve one   I was getting a 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed with the current    ws.Range("I" & RowInsert).Value = "0.5k"    So I'll have to have a think about I can attach the size data to the end of its respective line.

Comment: You can accept the answer I think :). Regarding the 1004 error: It might be caused by the fact that `RowInsert` is only defined in with in the first if-statement and you might need to place that line above the if-statement.